# Alternative to mssql_guid_string in PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

I found a couple of results similar to what I'm about to ask but unfortunately none of them provided a solution or direction to the problem I'm facing.

I'm reviewing a large **SQL Server 2008** database and I'm running some blanket queries such as running a **SELECT TOP(5)** on every table to get an idea of the contents.

I've encountered some **Binary(16)** objects in the results in PHP and of course PHP isn't able to print a readable version of the id easily.  I don't have the option of adding the MSSQL extension to make use of the **mssql_guid_string** function and I can't perform the convert in SQL as the select needs to be as generic as possible to work for every table.  I'm doing a foreach on a list of tables to return the data and print it.

So my question is:  **Does anyone know of an alternative to mssql_guid_string in PHP??**

The pseudo of what I'm trying to do would be;

```
1.  SELECT TOP(5) * FROM table1
2.  WHILE $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array{...
3.  foreach $row as $col print $col
```

The id's in SQL look something like this ->  **0xB0826E8A84CA6C418254E28BC0F749CF**

When printed in PHP they look like this ->  **X÷Eòv˜H½XšÔÛé«Ù**

Any help/thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Steve

Comment: If it was MySQL I would do a `DESCRIBE table_name` so I knew the datatype of each column and therefore which columns were going to need any special tweaking to output the data in them. I believe `sp_help ‘dbo.table_name` is the equivalent in MSSQL speak. This may help you get going http://maftahur.wordpress.com/2010/04/28/how-to-describe-table-in-ms-sql-server/

Comment: I was actually going to post a comment below Alvaro's answer (which is awesome by the way Alvaro!!) asking what you've just suggested Riggs! :)  Thanks for that.

Comment: sp_columns provides a more simple response.  It has the column names and data types which is everything I need.  sp_help provides a few different collections of information which would be more tricky to handle in PHP.

Comment: Ok, there you go. I am not that familiar with MSSQL DB's as I have not used them for years now. But you have obviously got the general idea I was trying to make.

Comment: One last comment from myself just in case anyone happens upon this for a problem similar to mine. DON'T use `exec sp_columns table` to get column information.  It takes too long to run on the DB.  My script ran for 91 minutes across all 3200 tables.  I replaced it with 

`SELECT *
FROM Northwind.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'tablename'`

Execution time for the script is now 2 mins!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the PHP side you can [dump to hexadecimal](https://www.php.net/bin2hex) and add a prefix:

```
echo '0x' . strtoupper(bin2hex($col));
```

From SQL Server you can probably cast to string (no idea about that).

Comment: Magic Alvaro.  This is why I love SO :D  Thank you very much.